# Dictionary keyError on dynamic value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, parsing

I have a code in my python file that is given below.

```
    data_to_parse = """
    Repo: 2msdsdodule-losdsdader
    Path: 2modsdsule-loasdsdder
    Components: 2sssss-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds
    
    Repo: 1msdsdodule-losdsdader
    Path: 1modsdsule-loasdsdder
    Components: 1libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds
        
    Repo: 3msdsdodule-losdsdader
    Path: 3modsdsule-loasdsdder
    Components: 3libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds
    
    """
    lines = data_to_parse.splitlines()#print(lines,'-----')
    result_list = []
    result = {}
    
    for line in lines:
        results = {}
        if 'Components:' in line:
           line2 = line.split(':')
           result['Components']= (line2[1].strip())

        if 'Path:' in line:
           line2 = line.split(':')
           result['Path'] = (line2[1].strip())
           results[result['Components']] = result['Path']
           result_list.append(results)

print(result_list)
```

But when i tried to run this it is showing me the error like :

```
results[result['Components']] = result['Path']
KeyError: 'Components'
```

.can anyone please help me relate this ?? I am stuck here. any suggestions any help would be matter.

Output i want like :

```
[{'2sssss-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds':'2msdsdodule-losdsdader'}
{'1libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds':'1msdsdodule-losdsdader'},
{'3libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds':'3msdsdodule-losdsdader
'}]
```

Comment: Please include debugging info such as the value of the variables `line`, `results` and `result` when the error occurs.

Comment: If the first condition was not matched than the result dict has not Components key.

Comment: @Phantoms is there any way to solve this ??

Comment: @Nehanegi what would you like to achieve? How the output should looks like?

Comment: @Phantoms I have edited the question can you please check ??

Comment: I pasted you the answer for this. I hoped it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Like kareem mentioned, the loop reads line by line. But the 'Path' line comes before 'Component' line has been read. To solve this you may change your code as:

```
lines = data_to_parse.splitlines()#print(lines,'-----')
result_list = []
result = {}
    
for line in lines:
    results = {}
    if 'Path:' in line:
        line2 = line.split(':')
        result['Path'] = (line2[1].strip())
    
    if 'Components:' in line:
        line2 = line.split(':')
        result['Components']= (line2[1].strip())

        results[result['Components']] = result['Path']
        result_list.append(results)
```

The difference is we changed Path and Component if code lines. With this code you may reach the result, which you are looking for. Personally I would recommend you to use list comprehension to avoid defining temporary variables. Consider the code which does the same thing:

```
lines = data_to_parse.splitlines()
components = [line.split(':')[1].strip() for line in lines if 'Components' in line]
path = [line.split(':')[1].strip() for line in lines if 'Path' in line]
result_list = [{components[i]:path[i]} for i in range(len(components))]
```

This code assumes that there are equal number of components lines and paths. If you have special conditions, you may need to change the code by adding conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The error appear because the first execuat `if` is second one because
In second iteration the second line have "path" and the dict `result` is empty yet then the key "Components" isn't exist then the error throwing.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is tio remove all of the empty lines and divide the list into chunks of 3.

```
data_to_parse = """
    Repo: 2msdsdodule-losdsdader
    Path: 2modsdsule-loasdsdder
    Components: 2sssss-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds

    Repo: 1msdsdodule-losdsdader
    Path: 1modsdsule-loasdsdder
    Components: 1libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds

    Repo: 3msdsdodule-losdsdader
    Path: 3modsdsule-loasdsdder
    Components: 3libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds
    """


def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]


lines = [line.strip() for line in data_to_parse.splitlines() if line]  # list without empty lines
result_list = []

for chunk in [chunk for chunk in chunks(lines, 3) if len(chunk) == 3]:
    result = {chunk[2]: chunk[1]}
    print(result)
    result_list.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_to_parse = """Repo: 2msdsdodule-losdsdader
Path: 2modsdsule-loasdsdder
Components: 2sssss-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds

Repo: 1msdsdodule-losdsdader
Path: 1modsdsule-loasdsdder
Components: 1libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds
    
Repo: 3msdsdodule-losdsdader
Path: 3modsdsule-loasdsdder
Components: 3libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds
"""
# print(data_to_parse)

lines = data_to_parse.splitlines()#print(lines,'-----')
result_list = lines
# print(result_list)
result = {}
# print(result)

for line in result_list:
    # results = {}
    print(line)
    if 'Components:' in line:
        line2 = line.split(':')
        # print(line2)
        result['Components']= (line2[1].strip())
        # print(result)
    if 'Path:' in line:
       line2 = line.split(':')
       result['Path'] = (line2[1].strip())
       result['Components'] = result['Path']
       result_list.append(result)

print(result_list)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be like this >>

```
data_to_parse = """
    Repo: 2msdsdodule-losdsdader
    Path: 2modsdsule-loasdsdder
    Components: 2sssss-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds
    
    Repo: 1msdsdodule-losdsdader
    Path: 1modsdsule-loasdsdder
    Components: 1libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds
        
    Repo: 3msdsdodule-losdsdader
    Path: 3modsdsule-loasdsdder
    Components: 3libmsdsodule-sdsds sds-sdsd-test sdsd-load-sdsds
    
    """
lines = data_to_parse.splitlines()

my_val = ''
result_list = []
for line in lines:
    clean_line = line.strip()  # remove white spaces.
    if not line.strip():  # skip blank lines.
        continue
    if clean_line[:3] == 'Pat':  # if line is path.
        my_val = clean_line.split(':')[1].strip()
    if clean_line[:3] == 'Com':  # if line is components.
        my_key = clean_line.split(':')[1].strip()
        result_list.append({my_key:my_val})

print(result_list)
```